# How to let google know i'm the verified owner of 3 websites running with same content

Tags: seo, search-engine

I have 3 e-commerce websites having same contents on it,the domain name is same but the extensions of all domain is different.How to inform google that i'm the verified owner of all domains.

I just wanted to let google know and seek permission to use same content is different websites of mine, so that it wouldn't affect my ranking.

Is there any code by putting which on the 3 sites, google will got to know that these same sites are of one company's????

Answer (score 0):

By "the Domain name is the same but the extensions are different" i guess you mean you have example.com, example.net, example.io.

if this is what you mean, these are considered to be three different domains. you should implement [canonical urls](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#1) including the preffered domain or redirect all traffic to what you consider the main domain. (e.g. redirect traffic from example.net and example.io to example.com)

For each domain you should use a [txt recod](https://support.google.com/a/answer/183895?hl=en) to verify ownerhsip in the webmaster tools, most domain providers allow you to configure this record for each domain on your own. Log into your account at your domain provider's site and search for DNS Management, Name Server Management, Control Panel, or Advanced Settings.

Then again, many CMS or e-Commerce systems support "website aliases", where you can configure your system to answer to different domain names, when all your domains point to the same server and often allow you to configure a canonical domain, so that you may even not need to run 3 identical websites.

Please specify your setup, there is not much to go on here. A good example would be:

> I currently run 3 Websites (example.com, example.net,
>   example.io)(Drupal) on 3 Servers, each has its own domain but they
>   have identical content. They do not use a shared database.

Comment: Thanks Rene for your reply. You have understood my points, but i'm owner of 3 domains e.g- example.com, example.net, example.co.in. I have rank on some keywords to example.co.in and now i want people also to find example.com on the same keywords, So i'm going to start SEO campaign, but since example.com uses same content as example.co.in, so google will not rank example.com. What should i need to do in this regard?? How i will let google know that all the domains are mine.??

Comment: If they are identical, there is no use for google to promote all 3 as told above, they don't wnat to show the same site thrice for the same keyword. Instead, you can set up canonical urls or redirects , so that you promote your primary site. this way, all traffic generated through alternate urls benefits the main url, increasing the rank of the main url.

Comment: when you choose your primary site to be example.net, then example.com and example.co.in will never show up in the search results, but when someone types in his local ending he will get redirected to example.net, so that example.net gets more traffic registered.

Comment: To clarify: 
Google does not want you to have 3 identical highly ranked sites on the same keywords, but only 1 which may be addressed through different domains. You shouldn't and won't be able to banish your competitors from the search results.

To verify ownership of domains, use the txt records. But this won't make your identical sites appear in the search results.